# mean / variance of beta distribution

Tags: statistics

Can someone please walk me through how to find the mean and variance of the beta distribution (with parameters alpha and beta)? Also, I have seen two pdfs for the beta distribution. One of them varies from 0 to infinite, while the other varies from 0 to 1. I was wondering what the difference between these two pdfs are?

Comment: You may be thinking of the [Beta prime distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution) as having support on $[0,\infty)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you know that the normalizing factor of the density of the beta distribution with parameters $(a,b)$ is $1/B(a,b)$, you know without calculus that the moments of a random variable $X$ with this distribution are $\mathrm E(X^s)=B(a+s,b)/B(a,b)$ and, more generally, $\mathrm E(X^s(1-X)^t)=B(a+s,b+t)/B(a,b)$.

The rest is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).